# What is mediation adapters?

Tags: android, admob, adapter, ads

Firstly, I used Admob first to get ads on my android app and now I would like to try Appodeal because their ads look better.

They ask me if I need a mediation adapters for my admob account. 
**Does it mean they will use ID ads from admob?**

**What is the profit?** 
They say it might reduces my income.

**If it's true why can we do this?**

Comment: Did you google it? there's a lot of info on this issue.

https://www.quora.com/What-is-AdMob-mediation-and-what-are-the-benefits-of-implementing-it

Comment: Yes I did, but haven't seen this one. Thanks. So I understand it's for publisher ? I'm not a publisher, I just want to monetize my app. So, should I use this #Udi Idan?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are a publisher. You publish space that is available for ad networks to display ads upon.

I strongly recommend you use mediation. It means that you can have a single AdView is your app and configure it to display ads from whichever ad network is bidding the highest at any point in time.

AdMob provides mediation out of the box.
Just add in the Appodeal (or whichever ad network) libraries and mediation adapter. Then on the Admob  web page choose your AdUnit and configure an entry for Appodeal.

Comment: Agree with you. I'm using Appodeal connected to my AdMob account with the help of Appodeal's plugin for Chrome. The effectiveness of AdMob alone increased 1.5 times with Appodeals algorithm.